# Displaying results of solve function in TI-89 programming (cubic equation)

Tags: ti-basic

I have a program to find principal stresses. In it, is a cubic equation that I would like to solve and display 3 results. Here are my questions:

1. is *solve()* function correct one to use in ti-basic to solve the cubic equation? if not, which is correct?

2. When executing the program in home screen how to display three values of cubic equation?

Here is my program:

```
princstr(xx,yy,zz,xy,xz,yz)
Prgm
a = xx+yy+zz
b = xx*yy+yy*zz+zz*xx-xy^2-yz^2+xz^2
c = xx*yy*zz+xy*yz*xz+xz*xy*yz-xz*yy*xz-xz*yy*xz-yz*yz*xx-zz*xy*xy
solve(s^3-a*s^2+b*s-c=0,s)
Return s
EndPrgm
```

In the home screen it just returs

```
Done
```

Thank you in advance!
P.s. Edits are welcome.

Comment: What is the output of this code that you wrote? (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/798474/To-Solve-a-Cubic-Equation)[Does this link provide good pseudocode?)

Answer (score 0):

You are not displaying S. Return does not work like return in other languages. In TI-Basic, Return does not return a value; it return control to the calling program. If you want to display it, you should do

`:Disp S
:Return`